# How to keep a php script running for 4 to 5 days using cron job?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have a php script in codeignitor framework. It works on complex calculation algorithm which needs to keep the script running for at least 4 to 5 days. But it stops after running for few hours. How can I make it keep running until the script finishes?

cron command:

```
13 21 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/project/index.php 'test/mytest'
```

Comment: `cron` is for periodically starting / running a script, not for keeping something running.

Comment: Cron doesn't "keep things running".

Comment: unless you think of something that might handle interruption you won't be able to.

Comment: Could you maybe describe what kind of algorhythm you are doing? Maybe you can do it in command line with some tweaks, or in faster languages for complex calculations, like Python or Ruby. If you control the server hosting the website you might consider calling command-line and run the calculations "raw" on your server's resources, which might greatly shorten your execution time.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it depends on `max_execution_time` in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

`set_time_limit(0);` will remove the time-out safety protocol PHP has built-in. Be aware there are more factors, like system breaks and apache/webpanel protocols, that might still abort the script if it runs too long. Some webhosters for example still abort your script, even if you remove the time-out limit.

Good luck testing!

Comment: since he is working with the shell command there is no server that will kill the script...

Comment: Let's just keep it to the point where the system might kill it itself or the timeout is surpassed. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: yep that is why I added my remark to my answer that he should think of any kind fo robust implementation concerning interruptiopns

Answer (score 1):

You could set your max_execution_time to 432000

But since there is always something else that could stop your script, I would considder making it interruption robust.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use GNU screen for doing this thing. Start a screen, start your PHP script, detach the screen.It'll run until you kill the screen.

Comment: I think if you do this, internally, the script will still timeout on itself, due to the rules the php.ini configuration has set. You have to either change the `php.ini` file or overwrite it using the built-in functions to set PHP settings only for that file. The issue here is more about keeping the PHP script itself alive, than the process.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you as another person said about the settings in php.ini file